# Is there a way to find what libraries a script doesn't have but needs?

Tags: r, package

I wrote a crazy long script that I'm trying to run on two computers. I just loaded it up into the other computer and it won't run. I think the issue is that there is a library that's installed on computer 1 that is not installed on computer 2 but am having a ridiculously hard time figuring out what it is. I can't find what the problem is or which library is missing, nor can I find it by searching the command (everything I find is already installed).

It would be useful to know what the actual library is offhand if anyone knows, but I'm also looking for something that identifies all of the packages/libraries required to run a script based on the contents of it.

This is the function that will not run:

```
dplyr::filter(opendap.catalog::params, 
              id == 'loca',
              variable == "pr", 
              grepl('ACCESS1', model)) |> 
  dplyr::select(id, varname, units, model, scenario, duration) |> 
  dplyr::arrange(model)
```

running with the very useful `climateR` package. I have that, `opendap.catalog`, and `dplyr` installed, but it still won't work, and is throwing an issue with the `|>` part of the script and not recognizing the `model`. I've also run through all of my usual suspects of libraries offhand and gone through previous scripts that I've recently run to make sure everything I can think of offhand is installed and it all is.

Comment: |> is new base R. What are the versions of R on the two machines???????? And do learn to post complete error codes and complete descriptions of setup: version of OS; versions of R; versions of packages.

Comment: It's not clear that missing libraries is the issue here but FYI, RStudio displays a message if you open saved code which calls libraries that are not installed.

Comment: Yes, `|>` is new to base R in 4.1. If you have dplyr installed you could replace with `%>%` in most cases like your example.

Comment: Perhaps have a look at : https://www.hmcm.co.uk/how-to-identify-which-packages-are-being-used-by-r-file/

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, the issue was the |> part, switching it with %>% made it run fine.